# Android edittext style to show vertical divider

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to make this vertical line divider between the drawable and the text in the edittext:
I'm able to achieve the outer box look that contains the drawable on the left and the input text on the right but how can I add this divider in between?

[image]

This what I've done so far:

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/background_dark" />

    </shape>
</item>

<!-- main color -->
<item
    android:bottom="1.5dp"
    android:left="1.5dp"
    android:right="1.5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- draw another block to cut-off the left and right bars -->
<item android:bottom="15.0dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Is this part of a list?

Comment: No, it's part of an edittext

Answer (score 0):

With this "trick" you can draw a vertical line in the background of the EditText:

```
    <!-- main color part 1.-->
    <item
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:left="1.5dp"
        android:right="1.5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- vertical line -->
    <item
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:right="1.5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

     <!-- main color part 2.-->
    <item
        android:bottom="1.5dp"
        android:left="51.5dp"
        android:right="1.5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

In this case the line will be placed 50dip from the left side, will be black colored and 1.5 dip width. (the difference between 51.5dip and 50dip)

Comment: thank u, I can see a line divider now but it's right above part of the text, how will I move the text to be around 5dp to the right of this divider?

Comment: you can set the android:paddingLeft attribute of the EditText. For example android:paddingLeft="55dip"